# Call Remote Kernel from NETLink

Tags: windows, .netlink, remote-access, kernel-startup

Is it possible to run a remote kernel from `NETLink` in some way as suggested by the second method below: `DoRemoteMathCommand`?

(Running a local kernel as shown in the first method works fine.)

```
using Wolfram.NETLink;

private void DoLocalMathCommand(string command)
    {
        MathKernel mathKernel = new MathKernel() { /* Setup */ };
        mathKernel.Compute(command);
        mathKernel.Dispose();
    }

    // or grid?
    private void DoRemoteMathCommand(string ipAddress, string command)
    {
        RemoteMathKernel mathKernel = new RemoteMathKernel(ipAddress) { /* Setup */ };
        mathKernel.Compute(command);
        mathKernel.Dispose();
    }
```